# How to mock an object injected in Controller while calling an endpoint in Laravel?

Tags: api, laravel, testing, laravel-5, mocking

*Example:*

I have a Route file with an endpoint `/something/cool`:

```
$router->get('/something/cool', [
    'uses' => 'MyController@myFunctionOne',
]);
```

And I have a Controller named `MyController`. 
In `MyController` I have a function named `myFunctionOne`. 
In the `myFunctionOne` parameter I have an injected service class named `MyService`. 
`MyService` has a function that calls an external API `callExternalApi()`.

**Here's how my controller looks like:**

```
class MyController
{
   public function myFunctionOne(MyService $myService)
   {
       $myService->callExternalApi();

       // do some other things..
   }
}
```

On the other side I have a functional test:

```
class SomethingCoolTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testSomethingCool()
    {
         // callin my Route Endpoint (real http call to my app)
         $this->get('/something/cool', [])->response;

         // do some assertions..
    }
}
```

My question is: how can I mock the controller injected service, since it's calling an external service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was easier than I expected :D

First create a mocking helper function named mock:

```
public function mock($class)
{
    $mock = \Mockery::mock($class);

    $this->app->instance($class, $mock);

    return $mock;
}
```

Then Mock any service you like, as follow:

```
   $mimo = $this->mock(MyService::class);

    $mimo->shouldReceive('callExternalApi')->once()->andReturn([
        "anything" => "cool"
    ]);
```